# Trigger event when part of template re-renders

Tags: ember.js

I'm having trouble using the [jQuery dotdotdot plugin](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) in my Ember.js app. I need to run the plugin on an element whenever its content changes so that it can recalculate the new content with the ellipsis. The problem is that Ember.js doesn't alert me when *part* of a view is rendered, just the main element. So if a model changes and updates my cell to have significantly more text, I have no way of running the plugin to clean it up.

Is there a way to be alerted when an expression in a template is re-rendered? I could watch the property value on the model, but I have dozens of boxes on the screen from dozens of different models, so I think it would be pretty inefficient (and slow my page down as it becomes larger). My current thinking would be to abuse a Handlebars helper:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('dotdotdot', function(str) {
    var id = generateRandomId();
    var content = `<span id="${id}">${str}<span>`;

    Em.run.later(() => $(`#${id}`).dotdotdot());
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(content);
});
```

This seems like a misuse of a handlebars helper though.

Comment: You may want to just use `CSS` for this... Way less of a headache. Check this out: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/ This works great if you are just looking to contain text within a `DIV` or something.

Comment: The `text-overflow` functionality only works with a single line of text, and I have multiple lines, so a CSS only solution won't work for me. (I know there are some workarounds for that, but none are particularly good.)

Comment: Ah, okay I should have taken a closer look at your requirements. Take a look at this article, if you haven't seen it: http://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/ There are some seemingly okay CSS solutions for multiline, and then some JS solutions at the bottom, too. Not sure if you've seen clamp.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the Ember way would be to create a view or (better) a component for that. Then you could stick an observer in there that watches the content and re-runs your javascript when it changes.

EDIT: Come to think of it, a Handlebars component isn't a bad option because it's a formatting thing and there's no additional logic. However, it seems to me the 'proper' way of using the helper would be to do something like this:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('dotdotdot', function(str) {
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(dotdotdot(str));
});
```

Maybe you can find the `dotdotdot` function from the plugin?

Comment: I'm a little worried about performance, so I don't know if having dozens (or hundreds) of components would work very well. I can definitely try though. Do you know if Ember.js supports nested components? I read somewhere that it doesn't handle them too gracefully.

Comment: Dozens of components shouldn't be an issue, why don't you just give it a try? Although given that it's a formatting thing, I don't think a handlebars helper isn't unreasonable.

Comment: I like the idea of extracting out the `dotdotdot` function. Unfortunately it's going to need a lot of inline CSS, but it should work OK. I'm going to give that a try first.

Comment: Good luck - can't you split the CSS out into a separate file?

Comment: It turns out that dotdotdot does a lot of calculations based on the current size of the element. I don't think it would be possible to do that work without the element being rendered first. It looks like I'm going to have to go the route of using a component.

Comment: Ah I see. I guess there are two options: either truncate according to element dimensions or according to character/word count. Seems like they do the former. In that case a component is probably the way to go.

Comment: So I ended up going the component route. However, it should be noted that the best way to be notified when part of a template renders is by using a Handlebars helper. You covered both solutions, so I would say your answer is best.

Answer (score 2):

We solved this in out app by making component that had no template. The problem we ran into is that dotdotdot is a little overzealous about it's DOM manipulation IMHO. It's constantly stepping on Metamorph's toe. Anyway, here is my solution:

```
App.DotDotDotComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'span',

  // Maximum height before the ellipse kicks in.
  height: 40,

  didInsertElement: function() {
      this._super();
      this.updateDOM();
  },

  // {Observer} Watches for content changes
  _contentDidChange: function() { 
    this.updateDOM(); 
  }.observes('value'),

  // Updates the DOM with the current values
  updateDOM: function() {
    var height = parseInt(this.get('height'), 10) || 40;
    if(this.get('state') === 'inDOM') {
      this.$().text(this.get('value'));
      this.$().dotdotdot({ height: height });
    }
  }
});
```

In your template:

```
{{dot-dot-dot value=body height="40"}}
```

Here is a jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wiqisate/2/edit

Hope it helps.

Comment: I kind of like this approach. I think I'm going to move away from dotdotdot soon, but I'll probably use something like this combined with some custom logic to add ellipsis.

Comment: Cool! Yea, dotdotdot is a bit hairy. I personally don't care, in general, for JS making layout decisions. But sometimes it's necessary. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little ambiguous, but here's my interpretation of it.  Let me know if this is correct:

- You render your view.
- You have some text, which we will call `someText`, inside an element.
- You run `.dotdotdot()` on the element containing `someText`.
- User input causes the value of `someText` to change.
- You want to, but are having difficulty, running `.dotdotdot()` on the element containing `someText` for a second time.

Is this correct?

If so, you can simply observe the `someText` content property and run `.dotdotdot()` every time it changes.  Something like:

```
updateDot : function(){
    ("#containingElement").dotdotdot();
}.observes('someText')
```

Within the responsible controller.

Comment: Sorry, I'll have to go back and make it a little more clear. This method might work, but it'll be pretty fragile. I have several dozen (possibly hundred) boxes on the screen, each of which has it's own model. And each box contains 4 to 5 fields from each model. The way I have my components set up would make this quite cumbersome, so it's a last resort for me.

Comment: Hundreds of models??  Are these really models, as in linked to view/controllers, or do you simply have an array of values?

Comment: They're full-blown models with relationships and all. I'm displaying a matrix of data (kind of like a spreadsheet), and each cell has it's own model.

Comment: ... Why?  Why isn't it just an array of data?  It seems like you're making your life one hell of a lot more difficult than it needs to be if you would instead have an array of objects that have attributes tied to each column.  I assume you have some reason for doing it the way you have, but it certainly seems a bit convoluted... whatever your reasons are though, they most certainly will have an impact on the issue being discussed here.

Comment: What do you mean why? They're individual records and their existence is much larger that the grid that I'm currently displaying them in.

Comment: The size of the record and what you choose to display are completely independent.  You could (and probably should, if I'm interpreting your set up correctly) store the information in an object array and just invoke the elements you need where you need them.

Comment: I wasn't talking about the size of the record, I was talking about it's purpose. This grid is only 1 of about 20 places that those records are used. I can't change my data model to optimize just for the grid.

Comment: You don't *need* to.  Well at least in most cases you wouldn't.  Perhaps you're doing something unusual that makes it not plausible to do this as an array, but so far nothing you've said indicates that.  If you want help, you really need to provide further information about what you're doing so that this conversation can move from theoretical to practical.